# How to remove an "Unallocated" partition

Tags: windows, partitioning, gparted, format, drive

I had Windows partition on my hard drive, but I uninstalled Vista, so I no longer need it. 
I'm guessing I need to log in with a Live CD, but when running Drive Utility and GParted on the CD, it showed a lock next to the drive, so it wouldn't let me modify it.
 
Any idea on how to remove a partition without formatting the drive? Thanks. :)

Comment: Unallocated just means free space - what do you want to do with the free space? Add it to an existing partition or create a new one? Can you make a screenshot of GParted showing the locked state? Normally, only the swap partition should be in use by the live CD system and that shouldn't stop GParted from extending/creating a partition.

Answer (score 1):

If the amout of unallocatet space is very small compared to your disk size, it could be that it's smaller then the minium for a partitition. In that case this overhead cannot be used by your system and you would have to rearrange all your partitions to accommodate your unallocated space.

Everything else was said in htorque's comment.